# Where to start on encoding a file into an image pattern

Tags: java, image, encoding

Lets say I have a small file ~5KB. I have all the bytes of that file, their values range from -128 to 128.

My goal is to transform the file into an image, so that it can be decoded with image recognition. Think Barcode or QR code.

So my question is, where to start on algorithms for encoding data into an image pattern? I assume it would be way too hard to encode 5000 byte integer values (-128, 128) into a pattern, so I'd first have to transform that into something of a smaller range - binary maybe? Then put all of that into a pattern.

Also, anything related to Java would be great.

Comment: "so that it can be decoded with image recognition" is a pretty vague. Ideally, you could encode three of your values into one RGB pixel. Send that bitmap via email, the other side can easily decode that image. That's probably not what you mean by "image recognition". So what restrictions do you have?

Comment: Sounds like you want to encode your data to an 8-bit grayscale image. Maybe 500x10 pixels? It's hard say with just 5000 bytes.

Comment: Nit: byte has a max value of 127, not 128.